# MySQL: Multiple select from some servers in one query?

Tags: mysql

Can I select data from some servers in one query?

MySQL:

> server1:
>       database:
>           users
>
> server2
>       database:
>           users
>
> serverN
>       database
>           users

Is it possible to select records from users tables from all servers with one query?

Comment: Is `users` a table or a database? You are confusing us.

Comment: database - DB name. Users - table name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5371062/1073631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. you can only use select on the same server you connected to.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it is often quoted that database engines aren't designed for this purpose. Here's something related to it [multiple_db_across_multiple_servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568618/execute-one-mysql-query-on-multiple-databases) may be this answers your question to some limit.